# 3D touch equivalence for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have attempted to develop a game using swift that leverages the 3D touch hardware of iPhones. However, as I was submitting my app to the App Store, it got rejected because the game *wasn't playable on iPads*.

My question is, what is the best way of implementing a similar functionality for non 3D touch devices? The way I am doing right now is by implementing the following method

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if self.didStartGame, let touch = touches.first {

        let maximumPossibleForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce
        let force = touch.force
        let normalizedForce = min(force/maximumPossibleForce * 2.5, 1)

        // Added game-related code here to modify scene accordingly

    }

}
```

When running the latter on non 3D touch devices, debugging the value of `touch.maximumPossibleForce` returns `0`.

Comment: Measure how fast you tap? Note that there are also iphones that dont support 3d touch.

Comment: The mechanic is to actually not lift your finger from the screen, but rather modify the force of your press. I obviously know that some iPhones also don't support 3D touch, which enforces implementing the aforementioned functionality in a different way.

Comment: Without support for 3D touch you can't detect the force of a press at all.  The closest you can get is to measure the length for the press i.e. the time the finger is on the screen.

Comment: Seems opinion-based. It's up to you to examine prior art. What does Apple do? If you examine how 3D touch features are handled on iPad by Apple, they are either omitted entirely or else long press is used instead.

Comment: How do you consider the latter to be opinion-based if I am asking _what is the best way of implementing a similar functionality for non 3D touch devices?_ I was trying to see if there's a best-practice alternative that people usually go for @matt.

Comment: The words "best" and "usually" say it all.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion you might have had - what I wanted to know is whether there are any paradigms or industry standards people usually apply when it comes to solving such a problem. Will take your comment into consideration for further posts though, and thank you!

Comment: "what I wanted to know is whether there are any paradigms or industry standards people usually apply when it comes to solving such a problem" And I replied, if you truly "want to know" that, look at what Apple does.

Comment: I don't understand why the aggressive tone - I have already done what you have suggested. I don't usually post a question on stack overflow unless I really believe that there's something new I can learn from the community. Again, thank you for your constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect force touch on devices that that don't support it.

But maybe you could use the `majorRadius` property on `UITouch`. It gives you the radius of the touch.

With the radius you can allow users that don't have a 3d touch device to control your game with the angle of their finger:

[image]

This is the code for the above example:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let pseudoForce = touches.first?.majorRadius else { return }
    label.text = "\(pseudoForce)"
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let pseudoForce = touches.first?.majorRadius else { return }
    label.text = "\(pseudoForce)"
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    label.text = "-"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't the latter even existed. Will look into implementing it!